# What is the order and time passed between the segments?

Tags: plot-explanation, too-late

Dennis Hauck's intriguing private detective thriller [Too Late](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2394063/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) is filmed in a small number of what appear to be single (but wandering camera) takes. These long takes are not shown in order or with a clear sense of how much time has passed between them.

What is the temporal order and how much time has passed between each segment?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Late_(2015_film)